# WebClient always returning same content

Tags: c#, php, webclient

I have set up a website, from which I can fetch random quotes of people.
When I browse to the website via browser, I get a different quote on each refresh (how it should be).

But when I use the WebClient, I always get the same page/quote.

Can someone explain that?

```
try
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("https://my.website.com"));

    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        try
        {
            XElement erg = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
            IEnumerable<XElement> r = erg.DescendantsAndSelf("value");

            foreach (XElement sitem in r)
            {
                //I reset these vars before each call

                _ID = Convert.ToInt16(sitem.Element("id").Value);
                _upvotes = Convert.ToInt16(sitem.Element("upvotes").Value);
                _downvotes = Convert.ToInt16(sitem.Element("downvotes").Value);
                _composer = sitem.Element("composer").Value;
                _content = sitem.Element("content").Value;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
        }
    };
}
catch (Exception)
{ }
```

This is in the PHP-Script on my website

```
$res = $mysqli->query("
SELECT * FROM QUOTES
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;");

while($z = $res->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo "
    <value>
        <id>{$z['id']}</id>
        <composer>{$z['composer']}</composer>
        <content>{$z['content']}</content>
        <upvotes>{$z['upvotes']}</upvotes>
        <downvotes>{$z['downvotes']}</downvotes>
    </value>"; 
}
```

Comment: You can try to disable the request caching: `RequestCachePolicy policy = 
        new  RequestCachePolicy( RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore); WebClient wc = new WebClient(); wc.CachePolicy = policy;`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your website depend on cookies (or sessions, etc.) to determine which quote to display?

If so, the difference between your browser and the webclient is that the browser accepts cookies, while for the WebClient each visit is like the first.

**EDIT:**

After your post of the web site script, I think the problem may be because the SQL Server is caching the query and returning the same result set for each call. A way to remedy that may be to fetch a lot of quotes from the server, then use the random function in the script to select one from that.

**EDIT 2:**

If you have design privileges to the QUOTES table, you can add a DISPLAYED column to the table. Then you modify your query as: SELECT * FROM QUOTES WHERE DISPLAYED<>'Y' ORDER BY....

After fetching the quote, you update it and set its DISPLAYED column to 'Y'. Again, since I don't know your QUOTES table structure, you will have figure out how to do that.

If there are no quotes with DISPLAYED<>'Y' you will have to reset the DISPLAYED column of all records to 'N' .

Comment: No, no cookies. Just SQL. When I use the WebClient for the first time, it shows randomly. From there on, whenever I refresh I get the same result.

Comment: I think you should post the code of your webpage as well as your webclient code for people to better analyze this behavior

Comment: Which language is the script? You may want to add that tag to the question. I also edited my answer, have a look

Comment: I ended up fetching about 300 quotes and going through them that way. Still no perfect solution though.